# A question about the existence of rational functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, rational-functions

I am reading a paper [Representations of shifted quantum affine algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.06996). I have a question about the existence of a rational function about the remark $4.4$

I'll briefly describe the problem.

> We let $\phi^+(z)=\sum_{m\ge 0}\phi_m z^m$ and $\phi^-(z)=\sum_{m\ge -q}\phi^-_{-m}z^{-m}$,where $q\in \mathbb{Z}$.
> In the paper the author proves that there exists a polynomial $P(z)$ satisfies $P(z)(\phi^+(z)-\phi^+(z))=0$.
> Then the author says that $\phi^+(z)$ and $\phi^-(z)$ can be seen as one rational function expanding at $z$ and $z^{-1}$ respectively.

I think this means there exists a rational function $f(z)\in \mathbb{C}(u)$ such that $f(u)=\phi^+(z)=\phi^-(z)$  from  $P(z)(\phi^+(z)-\phi^-(z))=0$

**My question** :

How can I get there exists a rational function $f(z)\in \mathbb{C}(u)$ such that $f(u)=\phi^+(z)=\phi^-(z)$  from  $P(z)(\phi^+(z)-\phi^-(z))=0$?

Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you write $\psi(z)=\phi^+(z)-\phi^-(z)$ your reference quotes the existence of a polynomial $P(z)$ such that the product $P(z)\psi(z)=0$. That is, if $P(z)=a_rz^r+\cdots+a_1z+a_0$ you have the relation $a_rz^r\psi(z)+\cdots+a_1z\psi(z)+a_0\psi(z)=0$ so that $z^r\psi(z),\ldots, z\psi(z), \psi(z)$ are not linearly independent. From this it follows that $\psi(z)$ is a rational function.

Comment: @ F Zaldivar  Thanks! But I wonder why from $z^r\psi(z),\cdots,z\psi(z),\psi(z)$ are not linearly independent, we can get $\psi(z)$ is a rational functional.  Maybe that's what's confusing me.